# How to control Sass Variable with javascript

Tags: javascript, sass

I have a Sass file which is generating a CSS file. I have used many variables in my sass file for background color, font-size, now I want to control my all variables through JavaScript.

For example, in style.sass we have

```
$bg : #000;
$font-size: 12px;
```

How can I change these values from JavaScript?

Answer (score 31):

You can't. SASS is a CSS preprocessor, which means that *all* SASS specific information disapears when you compile it to CSS.

Comment: Thanks GJK.but i want to change my variables before css generation. like some is doing in bootstrap themeroller, in the same way i wanted to theme my web page.

Comment: Well, I can tell you that there's certainly no Javascript library pre-made to manipulate SASS files. You're going to have to do it server-side (via Node.js if you want to use Javascript) using plain old file IO.

Answer (score 24):

**CSS**

```
:root {
  subTitleLeftMargin: 1.5vw;
}

.element {
  margin-left: var(--subTitleLeftMargin);
}
```

**JS or TS**

```
document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--subTitleLeftMargin", "6vw");
```

Comment: `document.documentElement.style` would not work server-side right?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: this changed a variable value but chnaged not effect anywhere @Krull

Answer (score 10):

I also needed this functionality, here's what worked for me:

With JS you can set a class to body, ex. `.blue` or `.default`
Now create a set of rules to extend from, which you'd like to set:

```
.default .themeColor {
  color: 'red';
}
.blue .themeColor {
  color: 'blue';
}
```

Now instead of having `color: $someColor` in your scss file, use it like this:

```
.someClass {
   @extend .themeColor;
 }
```

Now, if your body will have the `default` class, the color inside `someClass` will be red, and if body will have the `blue` class the color will be blue.

Comment: will not work with shadow dom or shadow dom emulation (like component style encapsulation in angular)

Comment: @Ziarno that is true, so in the case of Angular, you can put these classes in the main `src/styles.scss` file, which is defined in `angular.json` to be loaded into all components.  Then they will be available everywhere.

Answer (score 8):

- Use Sass, or any other variables to set initial values
- JavaScript sets CSS custom properties of the same name to
  update those values as needed (same name is just a preference).

You do not need to define CSS root properties because the Sass variable is the fallback and will be used initially. This allows you to do whatever you want server-side with Sass or any other style processor, and update the values client-side.

Here is an example of a color picker controlling the background-color.

[see Codepen demo here.](https://codepen.io/mcleary/pen/wveNGZv)

scss

```
$selectedColor: #000;

body {
  background: var(--selectedColor, $selectedColor);
}
```

html

```
<input type="color">
```

js

```
const colorInput = document.querySelector('[type=color]')

// Set the CSS custom property --selectedColor on the root element
// Now JavaScript controls this variable and everywhere you used Sass variables if you follow this pattern
const handleColorInput = e => document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--selectedColor", e.target.value)
    
colorInput.addEventListener('input', handleColorInput)
```

Answer (score 3):

I find [sass-extract-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-extract-loader) especially helpful for using with Create-React-App.

You can use it like:

_variables.scss

```
$theme-colors: (
  "primary": #00695F,
  "info": #00A59B
);
```

component.tsx

```
 const style = require('sass-extract-loader!./_variables.scss');
 const brandInfo = style.global['$theme-colors'].value.primary.value.hex; // '#00695F';
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript runs client-side (in the web browser), while Sass is generated server-side, so you have to find some way to bridge that gap.  One way to do this would be to set up some AJAX-style listening to send JavaScript events over to your server, and then have the server edit and re-compile your style.sass file.

Comment: Thanks katiek. but i heard that with the help ok node.js we can do this. 
[link]https://npmjs.org/package/node-sass

Comment: Hi @Ankit sir, is it really possible with this tool, please tell us how ?, now days in react official site recommend this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do what bootstrap do (ie editing fields to download a theme).

You'd have to:

1. Have the files on hand that you want to edit
2. Store these variables as a string, and use `.replace()` to search and replace variables
3. Output this string and compile it to a file and or zip it up for download.

I'd personally do this with php.

Answer (score 1):

Share data between Sass and JavaScript using JSON.

See related question https://stackoverflow.com/a/26507880/4127132

Answer (score 0):

variable in style

```
:root {

  --bg: #000;
  --font-size:12px;

}
```

change variable value by javascript

```
root.style.setProperty('--bg', '#fff');
root.style.setProperty('--font-size', '14px');
```

Comment: That will change a `css` variable not a `scss` variable