# How to modify a parameter's value in sass files from typescript?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I am trying to change a variable's value in "../myStyle.scss" file from myComponent.ts . I read that it is impossible to achieve it because sass file are compiled into css by the sass pre-processor and the variable disapears. Isn't there a way to work this around.

My variable is called $theme.
And I want to change it's value.

$theme: #5A352A;
and I want it to become $theme: #ffffff; when the user clicks

Comment: Refer to this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787845/how-to-control-sass-variable-with-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to control Sass Variable with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787845/how-to-control-sass-variable-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to work in a different way.

Basically when you compile the angular app , it will generate a css file where it substitute the variable with the value , wherever you used it.

So if you want to achieve a color change you have to create a other variable and other classes and swipe it in your class attributes (this is one way, check also ngStyle and ngClass in angular reference).

For example white-theme/dark-theme (the most common case). 
variables ->   `$black: #00000; $white: #ffffff`

Example classes:

```
.body-dark {
 background-color: $black;
}

.body-white {
 background-color: $white;
}
```

and swipe the classes in the html elements.

```
setDark(){
document.getElementById("bodyId").setAttribute("class","body-dark ")
}
```

the same for white.

Comment: Thank you. I already know this way but i find it very heavy everything that you want to change on your screen must have this attribute. And it gets heavier when your theme has many colors

Comment: maybe you can work with ngStyle and ngClass , could help to find a solution that fit your needs https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/