# React build fails when sass uses calc and var together

Tags: css, reactjs, build, sass, create-react-app

I am using *create-react-app* to build my application and it works without any errors or warnings when i run it on development mode. How ever when i use calc and var together in sass I am getting a build error when i run npm run build on the terminal.

```
transform: translate(calc((var(--i) -1)*-100%));
```

When i uncomment the mentioned code the build doesn't fail so i am assuming this is where the problem lies.

This is quite odd because it works perfectly when i run npm start.

The error message is the following.

```
yarn run v1.16.0
$ react-scripts build
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/styles/core.scss
ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 31


error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sass, but shouldn't there be spaces around the operators inside calc ?

Comment: There is an [issue for this on create-react-app's GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10880).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works when a calc() is included to calculate the substraction and when spaces are include between operators.

```
transform: translate(calc(calc((var(--i) - 1)) * -100%));
```

Comment: Also, make sure you don't minify out the spaces. We got this error because [Bootstrap's (already minified) CSS](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css) (which had the spaces) got minified again, removing the important spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Inside SASS variables are declared with `$` instead of `var(--i)`.
Also you have to separate numbers from the `+` operator with a space. instead of `-1` you have to write `- 1` for instance.

Check the docs about the [`calc` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Also, you can check this [documentation about numeric operators in SASS](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/numeric).

Comment: I am dynamically changing the value of --i using javascript. If i use $ to create variables i wont be able to change it with js right ?

Comment: You can not do that.check these questions [sass variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17787845/how-to-control-sass-variable-with-javascript). and [css values with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566203/changing-css-values-with-javascript)

Comment: if you are planning to change css values at a regular basis with react you could take a look to something like  [css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules)  or [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) to see if it fits you better.

Answer (score 0):

Use #{$i} instead of var(--i) for sass variables

```
transform: translate(calc( (#{$i} - 1) * -100% ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of syntax worked for me. I wrapped negative number in number sign and curly brackets: #{}
margin-top: calc(var(--element-size) * #{-1});
No more build error.