# How to bind CSS 4 custom properties in Angular?

Tags: css, angular

With the introduction of custom properties in CSS 4, I would like to bind them in Angular.

Normally, one would use custom properties like so:

```
<div style="--custom:red;">
    <div style="background-color: var(--custom);">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when using Angular's binding mechanism, it does not result in a red rectangle:

```
<div [style.--custom]="'red'">
    <div style="background-color: var(--custom);">
        hello
    </div>
</div>
```

So how do I bind custom properties?

Comment: You could try Sass instead. But have you thought about using a CSS class to include --custom...

Comment: @JGFMK Sass variables do not propagate like custom properties do. And I need to bind to the property which Angular can't do in a stylesheet.

Comment: I'm not getting your comments there. 1) Sass vs Custom Properties. 2) Bind to the property which Angular can't do in a stylesheet. Can you elaborate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11195043/495157 - This is admittedly jQuery getting Sass variables... is that the kind of thing you were after...

Comment: I need Angular to bind to the properties so I can update them at run time via a REST API. Sass variables are like macros and do not propagate down the hierarchy if they change like custom properties do.

Answer (score 8):

I think you currently cannot bind that easy, BUT there's a work around.
As custom properties benefit from cascading you could set the property in your component and use it elsewhere inside it.

```
constructor(
  private elementRef: ElementRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.style.setProperty('--custom', 'red');
}
```

I took it from here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9343#issuecomment-312035896, but the renderer solution is not working for me